# NSTimer problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer, nstimer, ipod

In my app I used the code below with a timer of interval equal to `1.0f/30.0f` which meant that it is called 30 times per second to call `incrementSpeed`. I notice in the log file that the value of `moduloResult` is equal to '0' for a second and `incrementSpeed` is called 30 times every 5 seconds, but I want it to call it just 1 time for every 5 seconds.

```
- (void)move:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

   // ...
    CGFloat moduloResult = (float)((int)time % (int)5);
    NSLog(@"mod = %f",moduloResult);

    if (!moduloResult) {
        [self incrementspeed];
    }

   //...

}

- (void)inctime:(NSTimer*) thetimer{
    time = time + 0.10f;
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", time];
}


- (void)initializeTimer:(float)intero {
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intero target:self 
                               selector:@selector(move:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)initializeTime {
     float theInter = 1.0f/10.0f;
     self.timescore = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theInter target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(inctime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)incspeed{

    deno += 0.01f;
    [fadeTimer invalidate];
    self.fadeTimer = nil;
    [self settheInterval:1.0f/deno];
    [self initializeTimer:[self gettheInterval]];
    NSLog(@"deno = %f", deno);

    NSLog(@"interv = %f", theInterval);

}
```

Comment: What value is time? Could we see its declaration and how you change/set it? It sounds like it gets rounded down to zero somehow. Try setting NSLogs earlier in the code too to see which value is getting zero'd out where.

Comment: the time is another NSTimer with interval 0.1f

Comment: Can we see that piece of code? What does that timer do exactly, increase it by 1 every time, or by 0.1f?

Comment: more edit for better see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `self.timescore`, `inctime:` is called 10 times a second. Each time, it increments the time variable by 0.1 of a second. So the time variable is the time in seconds since the timer began, rounded to the nearest 0.1 of a second. E.g. you'd get the same if you did:

```
... elsewhere ...
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval startTime;

- (void)initializeTime
{
    self.startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}

- (void)move:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
{
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceInitializeTimeWasCalled =
        [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceData] - self.startTime;

    // round down the nearest multiple of 0.1 if necessary, e.g.
    timeSinceInitializeTimeWasCalled -=
                              fmod(timeSinceInitializeTimeWasCalled, 0.1);
}
```

This line:

```
CGFloat moduloResult = (float)((int)time % (int)5);
```

Is called in a method that you state is called 30 times a second. Given that it's positive, the (int)time will round 'time' down to the nearest whole number. So moduloResult will be '0' 30 times — in the period between entering the fifth second and exiting it again. What you probably want, as hinted at in the code I posted immediately above, is:

```
CGFloat moduloResult = fmod(time, 5.0);
```

And even then you don't want to compare the result directly to 0 because floating point numbers tend to round in ways so as to be non-exact. If you're calling that method 30 times a second, I instead recommend:

```
CGFloat moduloResult = fmod(time + 1.0 / 60, 5.0);
if(moduloResult < 1.0 / 30.0)
{
}
```

So you're checking whether time is within the 1/30th of a second surrounding when time mod 5 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but what I can say is that timers behaviour can be a little unpredictable when you're at the edges of their precision. And you are doing just that. [Here from the manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> Because of the various input sources a
>   typical run loop manages, the
>   effective resolution of the time
>   interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of 50-100 milliseconds. If a
>   timer’s firing time occurs during a
>   long callout or while the run loop is
>   in a mode that is not monitoring the
>   timer, the timer does not fire until
>   the next time the run loop checks the
>   timer. Therefore, the actual time at
>   which the timer fires potentially can
>   be a significant period of time after
>   the scheduled firing time.

So firstly, you're not going to be able to have a timer that runs every 1/30th of a second. Even 1/10th of a second, which is what you say in your code, is on the edge of what's possible.

Also note that the timer still fires, even if it's late. This could explain why you're seeing the timer fire after the time you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert a float or double to a int, it removes its decimals. So time would be a whole number only. So it will always divide a whole number by 5, which means you will never have a modulo. Why did you actually convert them to ints? Try making them both a double and see if that helps. Might be mistaken, but i think it'll work.